# Android Nexus 7 uses xhdpi folder in eclipse and hdpi folder on device

Tags: android, android-layout, nexus-7

When developing on a Nexus 7, I know it should use the resolution in the drawable-hdpi folder (even though technically it is a tvdpi resolution device).  But in the graphical editor in eclipse it uses the xhdpi and when I render it to the device, then it uses hdpi.

I tested this by putting different images with the same name in each of the resolution folders to see what it uses.  Eclipse graphical editor shows xhdpi images and the device shows hdpi images.  This makes it hard to layout the screen.. any ideas?

Comment: the graphical editor sucks, it's just a bug. Go get AndroidStudio IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use drawable-hdpi? You may want to use drawable-tvdpi. Assets would be 1.33 * mdpi.

Comment: Thanks, using tvdpi did the trick.  I just had to scale the images themselves differently then when using hdpi.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be fixed using changing layout to tvdpi. Try using tvdpi for Nexus 7, Galaxy note 8 etc

Answer (score 0):

[image]

try adding tvdpi for the layout like:

**layout-sw600dp-land-tvdpi
layout-sw600dp-port-tvdpi**